# U-Boot, Boot and DTB

Tags: kernel, arm, u-boot

Im slightly confused how things are working UBoot Boot and DTS.

I have SBC Mecool VS RK3399 and producer does not support it at all I wanted still make use of it. Fortunately I have found that OrangePiRK3399 image is bootable (from SD Card) but it has one drawback - Audio trough Jack does not work as accordingly to dmesg
"rt5651 1-001a: Device with ID register 0xffffffc0 is not rt5651"

So I taught that I will recomile thingy things :D. I spent too much time on setting up OrangePiRK3399 toolset but finally I have made it works and was able to create new OrangePi bootable img.

And here is my problem/doubts

1. How and when I should somehow choose "mine" DTS (which is present) as I have seen that compile process is using OrangePi ones...
2. Do I really need to choose DTS or it is picked proper one during Booting? as I cannot find such argument in scripts?
3. If my device is booting up with Uboot coming from OrangePi will it conflict with Boot image using VS DBT?

If somebody could kindly explain it to me in a bit more friendly language that Kernel documentation I would appreciate.